# Git pull --rebase changes the commiter name to my name

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I was recommeneded to use git pull --rebase in order to avoid the auto merge messages that git adds when pulling changes from a remote repository.

When doing so, i see that commits that are being applied on my repository during the rebase are added as if they were committed by me, and not by the original committer.

Is this the standard behavior? or am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Don't avoid the auto-merge messages. Merge commits, like any commits, should be handled with purpose. History should be nothing but useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here: `git rebase` creates new commits, as they have different ancestors and possibly different content, and these new commits are created by you.

However Git makes distinction between commit name and date, and *author* name and date, the latter being the name and date of the original commit.

Comment: I always thought it creates patches from my own commits, takes the base ancestor commit from which my history diverges, and applies the remote commits and mine into a linear history...

Comment: this only applies to your commits. do you mean that the commits coming from remote have you as author after rebase?

Comment: Yes, commits coming from remote have me as author.

Comment: @lysergic-acid: mmh that's not what I get, can you add more details? the ideal would be a sample session with git commands

Comment: I will do a simple session to reproduce. Note that the Commit email field remains as the original, only the author changes.